Should we name our chat room?
As you know, we have a chat room! Where you are welcome to come and have a chat about... whatever you like.
I have previously suggested potentially having chatcast/organised meetings in there. To kick things off, I think we should name it. Why?
Cryptography

is pretty boring really. I mean, I'm sure we can think up something better  than that, to make a house a home. For example:

Gaming's chat room is named The Bridge.
Server fault's chat room is named The Comms Room.
Security's chat room is named The DMZ.

So, suggestions and thoughts?

Yes, if a good proposal comes around. If no good proposal comes now, it can stay "cryptography" without major damage for more time. Unfortunately, I now have no idea how it could be named.

"Alice's and Bob's Room"  (just kidding)

@HedgeMage actually I quite like "Alice's and Bob's Room", after all it is historical conventional notation in cryptography (this is the only field I've ever seen them used in, but apparently they are used in Physics too)

Thought I'd revive this discussion and make it a featured post so it shows up in our Community Bulletin.

Is having multiple suggestions per answer really a good idea?

@CodesInChaos, probably not, but there is a minimum character limit for an answer, so a lot of the room names might not be allowed as an individual answer unless we add some extra text to the answer. Perhaps that is better than the current practice though.

I'll give it another week, now that we are starting to get some interest in this. Then I'll use the top answer.

Winner chosen!!

How about "The Side Channel"?
(Besides being a recognized crypto term, as well as descriptive of chat as a secondary communications channel, it's also somewhat appropriate — in a silly punnish way — because a link to the chat room is typically shown in the sidebar on the main site.  Or, at least, it would be shown if we actually had people actively chatting there.)

The Crypt
Edited to just leave one answer. The other one is down there v

I'm trying to resurrect the thread. I wish I knew which people were voting for.

You're right, it should have been just one. Wonder if I can get away with making this the Crypt and posting another with the Knapsack :-)

@RoryAlsop, I say go for it. Once edited, people can change their votes, I believe.

Done :-) other post now just with knapsack

Eve's Lair
(needed to put some more characters to get this to post)

Echo. "Eve's Lair "is nice. Alternatively, it could be "Eve's nest"… so people feel right at home ;) (Too bad the chat is so abandoned/inactive).

How about Chosen Plaintext Room? Or just Chosen Plaintext.

We could all hang out at our "pad", hopefully not just the one-time though.

on-the-record
(a play on off-the-record)

Bletchley Park
............

The knapsack split out from my old post years ago.

decypher
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
